# Advice on ClickHouse Usage

Tags: clickhouse

I'm new to ClickHouse and have been reading both the docs and Altinity's blog to see if the platform is suitable for my company's need. I've already have an opinion about it, but would like to double-check with the experienced people here if I'm right.

Our API will be receiving events in JSON format and will store them on Kafka. We need to do some analytics on those events and display the results on dashboards.

Three properties of the object are dictionaries that can hold any properties that user wants, that is, we don't know the nested properties name/values.

Therefore, we can't map those fields to the resulting MergeTree table. Finally, those properties can be used in 'WHERE' clauses.

Is there a way to use ClickHouse to address this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not use ClickHouse until you have another choice.
ClickHouse is like a mass destruction weapon which is hard to control.
Use PostgreSQL or MySQl.

Comment: We're leaning towards an OLAP-oriented database that provides good integration with Kafka, such as ClickHouse and Druid. We were willing to give ClickHouse a try because it's easier to manage than Druid

Answer (score 0):

> Three properties of the object are dictionaries that can hold any properties that user wants, that is, we don't know the nested properties name/values.

ClickHouse needs a schema for tables. Although you can use [JSON functions](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/) that can be used on String columns containing JSON strings, those columns cannot benefit much from the speed that ClickHouse provides. Also, there is an experimental [SQL/JSON future](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/24148) which will bring dynamic schema capabilities but it is still in the experimental phase. For now, it seems like PostgreSQL or MongoDB fits your case.

Comment: Do you mean Postgres with Citus? We're considering it as well.

Comment: @AlvaroSeixas I don't have any knowledge about Citus. I've recommended Postgres because it has JSON capabilities.